# Should I use LL when assigning a value to long long c++

Tags: c++, c++11, declaration, c++14

Should I always use `LL` when  assigning a value to `long long` in C++?

Assuming I have

```cpp
long long myVar = 10LL;
```

Or If I have a member variable of `long long` type should I always use `LL`?

```cpp
A::A()
    : m_myVar(0LL)
{
}
```

What are possible dangers to not write `LL` or to write `L`?

**EDITED**
From  answers, comments  and further googling the dangerous is such a case

```
m_myVar = 1000000000 * 100;
```

if `LL` will be forgotten for `1000000000` or `100`  the overflow will happen.

Comment: You only *need* it if you want to use literal values larger than supported by `int`, otherwise the compiler is smart enough to convert it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so if I write `long long myVar = 10;` or `long long myVar = 0L;`nothing dangerous there?

Comment: The compiler should warn you if you need to be pedantic (always compile with warnings enabled). I tend to use it with `auto myvar = 0LL;` .

Comment: Nope, nothing dangerous, not for such values anyway. Just a normal [integral conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_conversions). It can however be useful to use the suffix as an aid for documenting the code, for future maintenance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you don't need to do that. A C++ compiler will make the conversion.

(For the avoidance of doubt, `long long a = 5000000000;` **is** well-defined on a platform that has 32 bit `int` and `long`.)

Sometimes though, particularly when you work with templates, you will need to let the compiler know the type of literal you need.

For example, if `a` is an `unsigned` then `std::max(a, 1)` will fail since 1 is a signed type: you'd need to write `1U` or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

In this code snippet

```
long long myVar = 10LL;
```

there is no need to specify suffix `LL`. The code is safe. There is used the usual arithmetic conversions.

As for this code snippet

```
A::A()
    : m_myVar(0LL)
{
}
```

then it is desirable to use the suffix because in this case the reader of the code can determine the type of data member `m_myVar`. That is it is desirable for self-documentation.:)

Comment: for this case if `long long m_myVar = 1000000000 * 100;` without `LL` a bug will be introduced.

Comment: @TM In your example you are using an expression instead of just a literal. And I think the compiler can issue a message.